# I see "Unregistered" next to some users in their profile page. What is this?

Tags: support, login

Some of the users have "Unregistered" next to their name. What does not mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed the same [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/902/anonymous-coward):

[image: Anonymous image]

---

If you want to answer a question, it is not necessary to login with your Stackexchange account. This option becomes visible when you log out and is show as below:

[image]

It means you can fill in whatever name you want to display (tested). This does **not** work for Meta as an registered account is mandatory.

Comment: Is it possible to convert your existing account to anonymous?

Comment: I believe it can only be done the other way around, your account is already been registered to a name etc. but it is possible to alter that information and use a fake name so it make you look like anonymous. There is a downside to anonymous accounts in my opinion, that is if you lose your cookie file before or without registering then all your progress is lost too, so I would just stick around with the registered accounts ;)